# Modify go standard library crypto/tls via vendoring

Tags: go, tls1.2, govendor

For my crypto research I want to create a scriptable go TLS client using a modified version of the go TLS standard library (`crypto/tls` and `crypto/rsa`). The `crypto/rsa` library needs to be modified in a way to allow Bleichenbacher's attack on RSA. Since this modified TLS client will be used on several machines (and for the obvious drawbacks of modifying a vital core library globally) I want these changes to be bundled alongside my project.

I have started by downloading the `crypto` folder from GitHub and putting it in the vendor folder of my go project.
The structure looks like this:

```
tls-client/
--vendor/
----crypto/
------aes
------cipher
------des
------...
------x509
--scriptable-client.go
```

Inside of `scriptable-client.go`, I try to use the modified TLS implementation like this:

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    config := tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true, CipherSuites: []uint16{tls.TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA}}
    conn, err := tls.Dial("tcp", "127.0.0.1:443", &config)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Connecting failed: %s", err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()
    log.Println("Connected to: ", conn.RemoteAddr())
}
```

However, even though I have made changes to the RSA implementation, the script still appears to load the global version of the crypto package.

When trying to use RSA encryption directly, I get error messages indicating the global version (installed via ubuntu snap) is used:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x50e1e5]

goroutine 1 [running]:
crypto/rsa.checkPub(...)
    /snap/go/5830/src/crypto/rsa/rsa.go:75
crypto/rsa.EncryptPKCS1v15(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc0000b5c8f, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0, 0xc000010040, 0x1, 0x1, ...)
    /snap/go/5830/src/crypto/rsa/pkcs1v15.go:42 +0x55
main.main()
    /home/username/Workspace/tls-client/scriptable-client.go:23 +0x486
exit status 2
```

What am I doing wrong? Is vendoring even the right approach for overwriting a core system library like this?

Comment: You can’t do this, because your code would see a different package from any imports within GOROOT. Why not just modify the source in place?

Comment: If I modify the source in place, the go script would no longer be easily portable to other systems. Additionally, other "normal" go scripts that want to use TLS would also accidentally use the broken version I am creating.

Comment: You should stop thinking of Go as a scripting language. There are no "Go scripts".

Comment: It's also not particularly difficult to compile your program from a separate GOROOT and distribute it normally. If you want to modify the Go standard library, it will need to be within the correct paths.

Comment: @Volker Thank you for pointing this out. The fast compile time of go run had me thinking it was interpreted!

Answer (score -3):

You can:

1. Fork that repo and modify the way it works for you. This way, you
   can import it and use.
2. Use a private modified package. For private repo, you need to edit your go.mod file and point to your repo